# Angular ngFor out of order

Tags: arrays, angular

I have an array of months. for some reason angular for loop does not follow the order of the array.
[How can that be fixed](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-i25npn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)?

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<div *ngFor="let item of collection | keyvalue; index as i">{{item | json}}</div>`,
})
export class AppComponent  {
  collection : {key : any, value : any}[] = [];

  constructor(){
    let i = 0;
    for(let month of moment().locale('en-US').localeData().monthsShort()){
       i++;
      this.collection.push({key : i,value : month});
    }
  }
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-i25npn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: collection is an array of object, so not put the pipe keyvalue (the pipe keyvalue is when we wnat to iterate over the properties of an object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To follow the order, replace:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of collection | keyvalue; index as i">{{item | json}}</div>
```

by:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of collection">{{item | json}}</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

According to the definition of `keyvalue` from the [docs](http://The%20output%20array%20will%20be%20ordered%20by%20keys.%20By%20default%20the%20comparator%20will%20be%20by%20Unicode%20point%20value.%20You%20can%20optionally%20pass%20a%20compareFn%20if%20your%20keys%20are%20complex%20types.).

> The output array will be **ordered by keys**. By default the comparator
>   will be by Unicode point value...

And therefore your keys(string) are ordered by default.

Remove the pipe `| keyvalue; index as i` from your `*ngFor`.